# Convert JSF**k to normal JS

Tags: code-golf

Many of you already know [JSF**k](http://www.jsfuck.com/). For those who don't, it's a script that basically turns any JavaScript code into something written using only `[]()!+`.

Your task is to build, using any language of your choice, a program which converts JSF**k into unobfuscated JavaScript.

- **Input**: A string with valid JSF**k code.
- **Output**: A string with the regular JavaScript code that has been previously JSF**ked to generate the input.

For this challenge, consider that the input string has only been JSF**ked once.

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) contest, so the shortest code, in bytes, wins.

Comment: @Michael but is the encoding unambiguously revertible? I don't think so... how do I decide if a some `[...]` array access was part of the original code or part of the obfuscation? same for all other constructs, really.

Comment: @m.buettner, I don't know, maybe it's not possible. I was looking at the JSFuck encoder (http://www.jsfuck.com/jsfuck.js) and maybe it's doable. Anyway, the good term for the question is not *interpreter* but *decoder*.

Comment: @m.buettner essentially, this boils down to a database of certain strings and constant expression evaluation. We should be given some definite specs as to what simplifications exactly are needed. Voting to close for now.

Comment: Okay, it's full of loopholes. I'm a newbie at this and I really thought carefully before posting, but my lack of experience made the question confusing. Could you guys help me making it better by editing it? I appreciate the comments as well

Comment: @WilliamBarbosa post it in the [sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1596/proposed-question-sandbox-mark-xiii?cb=1) first. That's the place for the community to help you polish the challenge before it goes live.

Comment: Only you can patch the loopholes. Specify exactly what parts of compilation need to be undone.

Comment: @m.buettner unfortunately, posting to meta requires 15 reputation and the sandbox hasn't been moved to main yet (nor is going to be)

Comment: @JanDvorak oh what... that's so counter-productive... we *could* help him out with closing this question *and* upvoting instead of downvoting.

Comment: In fact, it's only 5 rep on meta. Here is your upvote, go ahead and post in the sandbox please! :)

Comment: @m.buettner I've downvoted because I don't feel the question is going anywhere. I definitely don't want to upvote a post just to unlock some privileges for someone.

Comment: @JanDvorak I think we shouldn't discourage new users who *want* to write good challenges and listen to criticism. Since the sandbox *is* on meta and will stay there, downvoting is counter-productive. Closing is totally sufficient. I don't think a single upvote would harm anyone, and it would give the user the chance to actually find an entry into this community. But someone agreed with you and decided to downvote as well, because heck, why should new users be allowed to post in the sandbox (I guess)... and now he still can't post there. I don't think that's how we grow this community.

Comment: Can you please add some explanation what *normal JavaScript* means? It might not be obvious how the back-transformation has to be done. E.g. if I iterate the obfustator twice on some nice input, what is the suggested output? The original program or the input which was already obfuscated?

Comment: @Howard I'm not sure that you'd get different output after running the obfuscator a second time (since there would be nothing to obfuscate), so one deobfuscation should make it should go back to an unobfuscated state. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @professorfish It is, because `[]` is altered by the encoder. But that was only meant as an example where the transformation is not unique.

Comment: For those who are wondering, censoring the title is partially in compliance with the generally accepted answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238577/profanity-in-hot-questions-list/238581#238581).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Javascript - <strike>68</strike> <strike>55</strike> 51

```javascript
alert(/\n(.+)/.exec(eval(prompt().slice(0,-2)))[1])
```

Alternatively: (same length)

```javascript
alert(/.+(?=\n})/.exec(eval(prompt().slice(0,-2))))
```

Runs in the console of your browser. Only guaranteed to work with code generated by jsfuck.com with the 'Eval Source' option ticked.

Ungolfed:

```javascript
alert(
    /\n(.+)/.exec(                 // regex to extract code from inside outer function braces {}
        eval(prompt().slice(0,-2)) // remove the final set of parens () and evaluate the code
                                   // this results in a function, which will be converted to a string as 'exec' expects a string
    )[1]                           // get the first capture group
)
```

Comment: In a suggested edit that I rejected, @user3082537 suggested to use regex instead of slice, as in `replace(/^.*\n|\n}$/g,'')`

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript, 122, works with any input

```
s=prompt().slice(0,-2)
i=s.length
while(i--){if((l=s.slice(i)).split(')').length==l.split('(').length)break}alert(eval(l))
```

Pretty simple; it just goes back in the string until the parentheses (`(` and `)`) are balanced. The last three characters of the JSF output are *always* `)()`, so slicing off the last 2 parens and then finding the matching paren for the other will always work. (It works with input with `[]` too.)